# Opening a file by UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, uidocumentinteraction

I am using `UIDocumentInteractionController` for opening documents in my app. I have used method below for previewing the PDF file:-

```
- (IBAction)previewDocument:(id)sender 
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"pdf"];

    // Initialize Document Interaction Controller
    self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];

    // Configure Document Interaction Controller
    [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];

    // Preview PDF
    [self.documentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:down.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];

}
```

I have read that we can read files in an app from other app too by `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

In my app, How can I read the files from other app using `UIDocumentInteractionController`? How does all this happens?

Answer (score 5):

Previewing the PDF document and sharing.

Set Delegate Method:-
UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate

```
NSURL *URL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Your PDF Name" withExtension:@"pdf"];
UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController =[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];
documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
[documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];

- (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: (UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller {
return self;
}
```

If you have any confusion, click on the below link and read :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html