# UIDocumentInteractionController Action/Options menu not visible in first launch

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uidocumentinteraction

Action/Options menu is not visible in the first launch, it appears when I go to full screen mode and come back to normal mode. Attached screenshots for reference. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
let docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url!)
docController.delegate = self
docController.presentPreview(animated: true)
```

and the delegate method:

```
override func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        return self.navigationController!
}
```

and is there a way that I can change the bottom bar color (which holds the Action/Options menu button) to black?[image: Without menu icon first launch] [image: With menu icon after full screen mode]

Comment: from where you are launching it??

Comment: From a viewcontroller which is embed in tabbar and navigation controller.

Comment: make sure u are calling it after viewdidappear as is may creates problem from there too

Comment: you should try my code it may help you

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works for me

```
let docPrev:UIDocumentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: url!)
docPrev.delegate = self
docPrev.presentPreview(animated: true)
```

Delegate method:

```
func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
    return self
}
```

Comment: I can not return self as I need navigation bar on top

Comment: you will get navigationbar on the top

Answer (score 0):

Please visit below link:
[Opening a file by UIDocumentInteractionController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787248/opening-a-file-by-uidocumentinteractioncontroller)

Answer on above link suggests that in delegate method you need to return “self”. This is same as mentioned by Jigar. Also above link suggested below link which may helpful to you

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html